# как проверить наличие значения, в результирующем запросе...?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Прошу подскажите, как проверить содержится ли в массиве определенное значение, к примеру $name, которое по http сюда подаем?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row['name']==$name){

} else {

}
```

Comment: То есть Вы запросом получаете (т.е. волокёте к себе неслабый объём данных) всех юзеров, чтобы потом проверить что среди них есть текущий? Вам не кажется, что это... ммм... несколько неразумно?

Comment: Тем более если у вас будет куча записей в `$row` - то ваша проверка  `if ($row['name']==$name)` никоим образом не сработает.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе у вас верно написано. Я бы только добавил проверку на существование элемента в массиве вызовом функции [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) и проверкой возвращённого результата:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if (isset($row['name']) && $row['name'] == $name){

  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: Или лучше empty)

Comment: "isset — Определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением, отличным от NULL" Это, не совсем мне подходит. поскольку  нужно именно совпадение значений...., или я что то путаю????

Comment: Пгостите. Мне наверное надо высыпаться :)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше проверяй запросом на наличие имени в таблице
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = :name LIMIT 1